# Unity cloud build speedtree textures incorrect type after build

Tags: unity, textures, build-process

So I finally (after a few days) got unity cloud build to work.

When I build it using the unity editor everything is fine. However, when the cloud build service builds it I get some odd textures for my grass and trees:

[image]

Is there anything specifically I have to do to make sure this doesn't happen.

I don't know if it matters but I am using unity 2019.1 with HDRP.

Comment: Is your cloud build Unity version set to the same version you're using locally?

Comment: @Iggy Yes 2019.1

Comment: Do you have any `Scripting Define Symbols` in the local project? May need to put those in the `Advanced Options > Custom Defines`.

Comment: @Iggy where can i check if i have those?

Comment: `Project Settings > Player > Scripting Define Symbols`

Comment: @Iggy do i need add one for each?

Comment: @Iggy Hey this worked however there are still some shader erros compared to my own build do you know what i might be missing there?